# phoenix http://0.0.0.0:4000 css not loading

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

[resolved]

Hi people,

I've just started learning Phoenix framework for Elixir, and whem I'm accessing the phoenix http://0.0.0.0:4000 (localhost:4000), the page is loading without the CSS.

A part from that, everything is running as expected.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

my OS: 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

My Elixir version:
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]
Elixir 1.7.3 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 20)

thanks

Comment: How did to create this project? Did you include brunch support (default)? Are you getting any errors during the build stage for your assets?

Comment: This is what I am getting when running mix phoenix.server

[error] Could not start node watcher because script "/home/teddy/.../node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch" does not exist. Your Phoenix application is still running, however assets won't be compiled. You may fix this by running "cd assets && npm install".

Comment: I'm not getting any error when creating the project using mix phoenix.new

Comment: Sounds like you still need to run `npm install` in your assets directory. Phoenix (by default) uses an asset builder called brunch. That is what your error is saying, the binary could not be found in the expected place. So once you run the install command I mentioned, it should be working properly.

Comment: finally fixed it.I had to run `mix deps.get, cd assets && npm install && node node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch build` The command runs for quit long time but at the end the issue is fixed

Comment: Instead of writing `[resolved]` in your question, please post your last comment as an answer and click the accept mark, so this question doesn't remain in an unanswered state.

Comment: hi @AdamMillerchip, can you please explain further? I cant find the accpet mark link where I need to click

Comment: @teddytresormabulay click the blue "Answer your question" button at the bottom, and "Yes, I want to post an answer", then post the contents of your above comment as an answer to this question. After that, there should be an option to accept the answer you just posted.

Answer (score 3):

finally fixed it.I had to run `mix deps.get`, `cd assets && npm install && node node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch` build The command runs for quit long time but at the end the issue is fixed